# C#.Net AsSpan().Fill() byte[] vs Int32[] vs float[] speed difference depending on array length?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I've run into something strange, when using AsSpan.Fill it's twice as fast on a byte[] array as opposed to an int or float array, and they are all of the same size in bytes. BUT it depends on the size of the arrays, on small arrays it is the same, but on larger ones the difference shows.

Here is a sample console application to illustrate

```
internal unsafe class Program {
    static byte[]? ByteFrame;
    static Int32[]? Int32Frame;
    static float[]? FloatFrame;
    static int[]? ResetCacheArray;
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // size vars
        int Width = 1500;
        int Height = 1500;
        // Init frames
        ByteFrame = new byte[Width * Height * 4];
        ByteFrame.AsSpan().Fill(0);
        Int32Frame = new Int32[Width * Height];
        Int32Frame.AsSpan().Fill(0);
        FloatFrame = new float[Width * Height];
        FloatFrame.AsSpan().Fill(1);
        ResetCacheArray = new int[10000 * 10000];
        ResetCacheArray.AsSpan().Fill(1);
        // warmup jitter
        for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            ClearByteFrameAsSpanFill(0);
            ClearInt32FrameAsSpanFill(0);
            ClearFloatFrameAsSpanFill(0f);
            ClearCache();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.Is64BitProcess);

        int TestIterations;
        double nanoseconds;
        double MsDuration;
        double MB = 0;
        double MBSec;
        double GBSec;

        TestIterations = 1;
        nanoseconds = 1_000_000_000.0 * Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / Stopwatch.Frequency;
        for (int i = 0; i < TestIterations; i++) {
            MB = ClearByteFrameAsSpanFill(0);
        }
        MsDuration = (((1_000_000_000.0 * Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / Stopwatch.Frequency) - nanoseconds) / TestIterations) / 1000000;
        MBSec = (MB / MsDuration) * 1000;
        GBSec = MBSec / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine("ClearByteFrameAsSpanFill: MS:" + MsDuration + " GB/s:" + (int)GBSec + " MB/s:" + (int)MBSec);
        ClearCache();


        TestIterations = 1;
        nanoseconds = 1_000_000_000.0 * Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / Stopwatch.Frequency;
        for (int i = 0; i < TestIterations; i++) {
            MB = ClearInt32FrameAsSpanFill(1);
        }
        MsDuration = (((1_000_000_000.0 * Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / Stopwatch.Frequency) - nanoseconds) / TestIterations) / 1000000;
        MBSec = (MB / MsDuration) * 1000;
        GBSec = MBSec / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine("ClearInt32FrameAsSpanFill: MS:" + MsDuration + " GB/s:" + (int)GBSec + " MB/s:" + (int)MBSec);
        ClearCache();


        TestIterations = 1;
        nanoseconds = 1_000_000_000.0 * Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / Stopwatch.Frequency;
        for (int i = 0; i < TestIterations; i++) {
            MB = ClearFloatFrameAsSpanFill(1f);
        }
        MsDuration = (((1_000_000_000.0 * Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() / Stopwatch.Frequency) - nanoseconds) / TestIterations) / 1000000;
        MBSec = (MB / MsDuration) * 1000;
        GBSec = MBSec / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine("ClearFloatFrameAsSpanFill: MS:" + MsDuration + " GB/s:" + (int)GBSec + " MB/s:" + (int)MBSec);
        ClearCache();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static double ClearByteFrameAsSpanFill(byte clearValue) {
        ByteFrame.AsSpan().Fill(clearValue);
        return ByteFrame.Length / 1000000;
    }
    static double ClearInt32FrameAsSpanFill(Int32 clearValue) {
        Int32Frame.AsSpan().Fill(clearValue);
        return (Int32Frame.Length * 4) / 1000000;
    }
    static double ClearFloatFrameAsSpanFill(float clearValue) {
        FloatFrame.AsSpan().Fill(clearValue);
        return (FloatFrame.Length * 4) / 1000000;
    }
    static void ClearCache() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ResetCacheArray.Length; i++) {
            sum += ResetCacheArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine it outputs the following:

```
ClearByteFrameAsSpanFill: MS:0,4913 GB/s:18 MB/s:18318
ClearInt32FrameAsSpanFill: MS:0,4851 GB/s:18 MB/s:18552
ClearFloatFrameAsSpanFill: MS:0,458 GB/s:19 MB/s:19650
```

It varies a little from run to run, + - a few GB/s but roughly each operation takes the same amount of time.

Now when i change the size variables to: `Width = 4500, Height = 4500` then it outputs the following:

```
ClearByteFrameAsSpanFill: MS:3,4015 GB/s:23 MB/s:23813
ClearInt32FrameAsSpanFill: MS:7,635 GB/s:10 MB/s:10609
ClearFloatFrameAsSpanFill: MS:7,4429 GB/s:10 MB/s:10882
```

This will obviously change depending on ram speed from machine to machine, but on mine at least it is as such, on "small" arrays it is the same, but on large arrays filling a byte array is twice as fast as a int or float array of same byte length.
Does anyone have an explanation of this?

Answer (score 4):

You are testing filling the byte array with 0 and filling the int array with 1:

```
ClearByteFrameAsSpanFill(0);
ClearInt32FrameAsSpanFill(1);
```

These cases have different optimisations.

If you fill an array of bytes with any value it will be around the same speed, because there's a processor instruction to fill a block of bytes with a specific byte value.

Although there may be processor instructions to fill an array of int or float values with non-zero values, they are likely to be slower than filling the block of memory with zero values.

I tried this out with the following code using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet):

```
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
public class UnderTest
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void FillBytesWithZero()
    {
        _bytes.AsSpan().Fill(0);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void FillBytesWithOne()
    {
        _bytes.AsSpan().Fill(1);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void FillIntsWithZero()
    {
        _ints.AsSpan().Fill(0);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void FillIntsWithOne()
    {
        _ints.AsSpan().Fill(1);
    }

    const int COUNT = 1500 * 1500;

    static readonly byte[] _bytes  = new byte[COUNT * sizeof(int)];
    static readonly int[]  _ints   = new int[COUNT];
}
```

With the following results:

For `COUNT = 1500 * 1500`:

```
|            Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median |
|------------------ |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|
| FillBytesWithZero | 299.7 us |  7.82 us | 22.95 us | 299.3 us |
|  FillBytesWithOne | 305.6 us | 11.46 us | 33.80 us | 293.3 us |
|  FillIntsWithZero | 322.4 us |  2.37 us |  2.10 us | 321.6 us |
|   FillIntsWithOne | 502.9 us | 27.68 us | 81.60 us | 534.4 us |
```

For `COUNT = 4500 * 4500`:

```
|            Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
|------------------ |---------:|----------:|----------:|
| FillBytesWithZero | 2.554 ms | 0.0307 ms | 0.0240 ms |
|  FillBytesWithOne | 2.632 ms | 0.0522 ms | 0.1101 ms |
|  FillIntsWithZero | 4.169 ms | 0.0258 ms | 0.0229 ms |
|   FillIntsWithOne | 4.979 ms | 0.0488 ms | 0.0433 ms |
```

Note how filling a byte array with 0 or 1 is significantly faster.

If you inspect the source code for `Span<T>.Fill()` you'll see this:

```
public void Fill(T value)
{
    if (Unsafe.SizeOf<T>() == 1)
    {
        // Special-case single-byte types like byte / sbyte / bool.
        // The runtime eventually calls memset, which can efficiently support large buffers.
        // We don't need to check IsReferenceOrContainsReferences because no references
        // can ever be stored in types this small.
        Unsafe.InitBlockUnaligned(ref Unsafe.As<T, byte>(ref _reference), Unsafe.As<T, byte>(ref value), (uint)_length);
    }
    else
    {
        // Call our optimized workhorse method for all other types.
        SpanHelpers.Fill(ref _reference, (uint)_length, value);
    }
}
```

This explains why filling a byte array is faster than filling an int array: It uses `Unsafe.InitBlockUnaligned()` for a byte array and `SpanHelpers.Fill(ref _reference, (uint)_length, value);` for a non-byte array.

`Unsafe.InitBlockUnaligned()` happens to be more performant; it's implemented as an intrinsic which performs the following:

```
ldarg .0
ldarg .1
ldarg .2
unaligned. 0x1
initblk
ret
```

Whereas [`SpanHelpers.Fill()`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/SpanHelpers.T.cs,22fac8ad1f92d5ab) is much less optimised.

It tries its best, using vectorised instructions to fill the memory if possible, but it can't compete with `initblk`. (It's too long to post here, but you can follow that link to look at it.)

One thing this doesn't explain is why filling an int array with zeroes is slightly faster than filling it with ones. To explain this you'd have to look at the actual processor instructions that the JIT produces, but it's definitely faster to fill a block of bytes with all  0's than it is to fill a block of bytes with 1,0,0,0 (which it would have to do for an int value of 1).

It's probably down to the comparative speeds of instructions like `rep stosb` (for bytes) and `rep stosw` (for words).

The outlier in these results is that the `unaligned.1 initblk` opcode sequence is about 50% faster for the smaller block size. The other times all scale up by approximately the increase in size of the memory block, i.e. around 9 times slower for the blocks that are 9 times bigger.

So the remaining question is: Why is `initblk` 50% faster per-byte for smaller buffer sizes (2_250_000 versus 20_250_000 bytes)?

Comment: I had no idea about the different value making a difference, but is not actually the problem i meant, i had not even noticed it. Look at ratio between FillBytesWithZero vs FillIntsWithZero respectively for 1500x1500 and 4500x4500, "299.7 us" vs "322.4 us" almost the same, but then in the 4500 buffer test it is "2.554 ms" vs "4.169 ms". Now calculate the difference in gbit/s write speed to memory, on the larger buffer the FillIntsWithZero is substancially slower. This is what i am trying to understand

Comment: @Lasse The actual outlier is the speed of filling a smaller byte buffer, which is somewhat faster than filling a larger byte buffer (when normalised). The other times scale up by around 9, which is what you'd expect for a buffer with 9 times as many bytes.

Comment: Filling a block of memory (/bytes) with zeros is one of the most common things the CLR does. Every time you `new` up a reference type instance, the runtime will zero it out. Of course it's going to be seriously optimized